# How to increase the signal power of a wi-fi card?

Tags: wireless

I use an atheros card that requires ath9k driver. Are there any tools that can be used to increase the signal power of the wi-fi card?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the commands in the iwconfig man pages:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower 15
```

or

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower 30mW
```

Answer (score 5):

If your issue is getting signal in your home or business only, perhaps you want to consider dealing with the other side of the equation (the AP or router). I have replaced the standard rubber duck antennas on my AP with higher gain equivalent... also, if you can often add on an external antenna to your computer side wifi device.

Comment: I use my laptop itself as an AP. Here is how I set it up: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21679/script-to-setup-ubuntu-as-a-wireless-access-point-on-a-bridge-mode