# Unable to connect my Android Phone to my laptop using as a hotspot

Tags: 11.10, wireless

I am using a 3G dongle. And I want to use internet on my Android phone.

See following screenshot, I press the button but it just give the message that connection established and after that, it came into its original state.

What network should I select in the combo?

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to use the internet connection of your computer on android phone. Hotspot button actually does not create a hotspot in ubuntu instead creates an ad-hoc.
 First of all as we all know stock rom of android i.e. the one which comes with the phone does not support ad-hoc mode (surprisingly), and even ice-cream sandwich (android 4.0) won't support ad-hoc mode. So, we need to create an access point (hotspot) using Ubuntu to which any android phone can easily connect. In windows you can use connectify to do that and it works perfectly well but with Ubuntu you may have certain problems, depending on whether your wifi-card supports access point mode (master mode) or not. Now, even if your wifi-card supports access point mode, the next problem is whether the driver of your wifi-card supports AP mode or not, if it does then the problem is solved and if does not then you have three options:

1- Wait till the driver recieves an update for AP mode. (many wifi-card drivers are still in staging stage)

2- Buy a wifi-dongle and make sure it supports AP mode on ubuntu.

3- Use windows, where connectify will do the job for you.

If you are interested you can post the name of your wifi-card driver so that i can help you further. command: lshw -c network

Comment: +1, thanks, I didn't know there is a difference between AP and ad-hoc. So here is my driver: ath9k. How do I see if it supports master mode? Would it be listed under capabilities?

Comment: @ adnan for answer. I run the command and come up with this wireless card: `PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection`. Here is the full result screenshot http://i.imgur.com/JHwPZ.png. So if you can tell, does it support to make an access point?

Comment: Your driver is iwl3945 which unfortunately does not support AP mode yet. This means it is not possible to create an AP on ubuntu. The only options are using connectify on windows or cyanogen mod on your android which supports ad-hoc.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use ath9k driver, you will be pleased to know that supports all the modes. To create a hotspot follow the link:
[How to stop Wireless AP Hosting using Network Manager on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21679/script-to-setup-ubuntu-as-a-wireless-access-point-on-a-bridge-mode)

Comment: I'm not so sure about this. Yes, the driver may support it, but not necessarily the hardware. In that case, you're still out of luck.