# Application for sharing mobile broadband with other computers(hotspot)

Tags: networking, broadband

I would like to know whether we have any application in ubuntu software center for sharing mobile broadband across other computers, making my computer act as wifi hotspot.

If there are no applications for that, any link on how to achieve it will be helpful.

I am running ubuntu 11.10

Thanks

Comment: [Internet Connection Sharing](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing) in the Ubuntu documentation may help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot make Wi-Fi hotspot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/76981/cannot-make-wi-fi-hotspot)

Answer (score 1):

First, [check if your network card supports the infrastructure mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106745/how-to-find-out-if-my-card-supports-infrastructure-mode/109324#109324). If it does, well and good. If it doesn't, you'll have to use the ad-hoc mode.

Either way, the steps to be followed are given here [at this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104264/mobile-broadband-sharing-over-adhoc-wireless/109358#109358).